# Difficulty in connecting Lua to redis server

Tags: sockets, lua, redis

I have problem with connecting to redis server. I have installed **redis-lua (2.0.4-1)** and **luasocket (3.0rc1-2)** using luarocks. I have just run `luarocks install redis-lua`. When I call `redis.connect` I get error:

```
Lua 5.1.5  Copyright (C) 1994-2012 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> local redis = require 'redis'
> local client = redis.connect('127.0.0.1', 6379)
stdin:1: attempt to index global 'redis' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
        stdin:1: in main chunk
        [C]: ?
>
```

And I have no idea why...

Comment: Have you gone through the docs here: https://github.com/keplerproject/luarocks/wiki/Using-LuaRocks and checked that your LUA_PATH and similar are properly set up ?

Comment: Just do not use `local` in command line interpreter.

Comment: Works without `local`. I have just tried to make `.lua` file and there it works with `local`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is difference when you're executing in interactive mode, or via a script. When in an the interactive lua shell, your `local` variables/runtime are scoped to that particular level of execution. This is why

```
local redis = require 'redis'
```

will provide you the `redis` variable only in that statement line. You'd have to connect to the server in same statement line:

```
> local redis = require 'redis'; local client = redis.connect('127.0.0.1', 6379); -- so other statements
```

Alternatively, in interactive mode, just do not use `local` scope.